# Preserve the tab spacing and white spaces in attributes of XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a very basic knowledge on C# and XML. I am trying to load an XML document using XMLDocument and then edit the values of some attributes of the XML and finally save the document with the changes. The problem I am facing is, I cannot get the same formatting that i have in my original document after editing and saving it.
For example the original XML document looks like below,

```
<M A="XML">                                                                                                       
<N  A="XMLLINE1"                    B="1"         C="2" D="3"           D="4" />
<N  A="XMLLINE2"                    B="5"         C="6" D="7"           D="8" /> 
</M>
```

After editing the value of B ="1" to B="10", I save the document. Now the spacing between the attributes A,B,C and D are not staying the same. Is there any way to preserve those spaces as they are and just edit the values and save the document?
The requirement for this document is to have those spaces as they are in original document.
Thank

Comment: Does this XML file end up being parsed by something that is not an XML parser?

Comment: Are you viewing the input and output XML in the same viewer?  Sometimes when viewing XML in say a web browser, the browser itself may alter the spacing in the elements to ignore some white space.

Comment: @RacerNerd I am using the Notepad++ to view the XML.

Comment: @Matthew I am using the XMLElement and XMLNodelist to access the attributes and then I am changing the required attribute value by specifying the index of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. If you want to preserve the space, better you can write your own class to generate XML by using StringBuilder or stream or you can use XMLWriter(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter_members(v=vs.71).aspx) to manually format your document.